# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Python type UUID cannot be converted

Tags: python, mysql, uuid

I have created a table in mysql

```
create table authorization(
email varchar(50),
orgID int(10),
candidateID varchar(255)
);
```

I am trying to generate uuid for candidateID in the table which uses uuid v4. I am trying to upload the information in to database through python code.

```
file = 'mycsvfile.csv'
data = [row for row in csv.reader(open(file,'r'))]
...
db_data = []
for row in data:
    id = uuid.uuid4()
    temp = {}
    temp['email'] = row[13]
    temp['orgID'] = row[1]
    temp['candidateID'] = id
    db_data.append(temp)
cols = ['email', 'orgid', 'candidateid']
try:
   Mysqlfunction.bulk_insert(table, cols, db_data, **CONFIG['database']['test'])
except Exception as error:
   print(error)
```

I am getting error

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Python type UUID cannot be converted
```

checking some [links](https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/) I was able to execute the query using uuid4() without any problem

```
insert into authorization(email, orgID, candidateID) values("maria@email.com", 1, (select uuid()));
```

Is there is any way to directly use the uuid in variable so that i need not run mysql every time for generating uuid ?

Comment: cast it to a string like so `str(uuid.uuid4())`

Comment: Or get a 32-character hexadecimal string representation with `uuid.uuid4().hex`.

Comment: str(uuid.uudi4()) worked !